# SSIS "Execute SQL Server Agent Job Task" passing parameters to an SQL Agent Job

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

I have an SQL Agent Job "X" that executes an SSIS package named "Y".

"X" passes parameters to "Y".

The SQL Agent Job "X" is invoked by an SSIS package named "Z" using an "Execute SQL Server Agent Job Task".

Currently I cant see any way of passing parameters from "Z" to "X" which in turn will be passed to "Y".

Can some one please let me know if there is something I am missing here.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you can't pass parameters to a job.

What you can do is populate a table with the parameters you want to pass, so package `Z` would populate the table with the parameters you want to pass to package `Y`.   Then package `Y` would read those parameters from the table.